# How to generate random number using multiple seed values?

Tags: random, seed

I need to generate random numbers based on multiple seed values, need some ideas on how to do this.

Sample situation: Say you're coding a procedurally generated sci-fi game, that needs to create planets (size,type,resources,etc) as the player flies into a certain solar system. You have a game ID, and X,Y,Z coordinates of the planet. Now what to feed the random number generator? I can't just add the numbers up, of course, as planet (1,2,3) would be exactly the same as planet (3,2,1). What's a coder to do?

Comment: Any reason not to just use the time as a seed? Do you want reproducible results?

Comment: Why do you need a new seed every time you want a new random number? Just seed once at the beginning of the program; that's how random generators were designed to work.

Comment: @larsmans, yes I want reproducible results!

Comment: @MrLister If I seed in the beginning, the results will not be reproducible, as I cannot generate the entire galaxy at once. I need to generate one solar-system at a time, and I do not know in what order the player will explore the systems.

Comment: "mercenne_twister_engine class can be seeded in two ways - with a single unsigned long value, or with seed_seq instance that wraps an arbitrarily large array of integers."

Perhaps that's what I'm looking for! :) Now to figure out how to use it, documentation is scarce...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you always need the same seed every time for the set of coordinates: just encrypt a concated string with MD5 or some other hash algorithm. md5("1,2,3") is not the same as md5("3,2,1"). Or if you need a purely numeric string, use something like: "first digit * 9" + "second digit * 8" + "third digit * 7" that will give you more variety.

If you don't, use the above methods with a random number.

In this case, pseudo random will be good enough.

Comment: Why not "first digit*100 + second digit*10 + third digit"?

Comment: That's a nice idea! A little bit of pseudo-randomness added to the mix, like?

Comment: I tried "seed = gameid + x * 4444 + y * 2222" with awful repeating results, not random at all... then exchanged 4444 with 1234 and 2222 with 5678 and not it looks pretty good.. :)